# using TaxonomySession from SharePoint web part and visual web part

Tags: web-part, managed-metadata, sandbox-solution

Can TaxonomySession be used at SharePoint visual web part and web part on sandbox? I tested a simple code as following,

> > protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
> >         {
> >          try{
> >                SPSite currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
> >                TaxonomySession taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(currentSite);
> >         }
> >         catch (Exception ex) { }
> >         finally{}
> >         }

and got the error message as below,

Web Part Error: Sandboxed code execution request failed.

[SPUserCodeExecutionPipelineFailedException: Sandboxed code execution request failed.]
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionManager.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPSite site, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartRemoteExecutionHelper.<>c_*DisplayClassa.b*_9() 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartRemoteExecutionHelper.ExecuteRequestInSandBox(HttpContext context, SPWeb web, SPWebPartManager manager, SPUserCodeWebPart userCodeWebPart)

[RemotingException: Server encountered an internal error. For more information, turn off customErrors in the server's .config file.]

Server stack trace:

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPUserCodeExecutionHostProxy.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String affinityBucketName, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext) 
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionManager.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPSite site, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)

Answer (score 2):

Microsodt.SharePoint.Taxonomy.dll isn't supported in Sandboxed solutions

For an overview of which parts of SharePoint is available see MSDN article [Available and Unavailable SharePoint Assemblies from Sandboxed Solutions in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615456)